# C++ How to preserve string capacity when copying

Tags: c++, string, insert, resize, capacity

**EDIT** (original post in edit history)

I'm able to reproduce my problem with this example:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_BUFFER 30

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    vector<string> myVec = { "hey","asd","haha" };
    vector<string> clone;

    for (int i = myVec.size(); i--;) {
        myVec[i].reserve(myVec[i].size() + MAX_BUFFER);
        clone.push_back(myVec[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Add a breakpoint before *return 0;* . Now, inspect strings that are in myVec and clone. **Their capacity is not the same!**

Comment: What do you mean by "the reserve space doesn't stay", what makes you think that?

Comment: I edited the example, turns out that was not the problem (my code is kind of big). But now, you can see that the capacity does indeed decrease, if you run that second code.

Comment: @anon_user Don't try to do C in C++. If you want to append `buffer` to a `std::string`, use `myString.append(buffer, bufferLen)` and the `std::string` will automatically resize if require.

Comment: @Holt, I doubt there's a compiler on earth which is able to optimize that. I will most likely use structs with size_t length and flexible array of chars.

Comment: @anon_user You'd be surprised. Reserving capacity in C++ in useful if you are going to add a lots of elements and you know how many you are going to add, so you do not want to do a lots of small reallocation but just a big one. If you are only going to append a buffer once, then you only need one reallocation, whether you do it prior to `.append` using `.reserve` or let the compiler do it in `append` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The capacity is not requested to be copied to be same when `std::string` being copied.

[$21.3.1.2/2 basic_string constructors and assignment operators
[string.cons]](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.cons#2):

> ```
> Table 49 — basic_string(const basic_string&) effects
> Element   Value
> data()    points at the first element of an allocated copy of the array whose first element is pointed at by str.data()
> size()    str.size()
> capacity()    a value at least as large as size()
> ```

The only guarantee is the capacity of the string will be at least as large as its size after copying.

It means you have to do this by yourself:

```
for (int i = myVec.size(); i--;) {
    myVec[i].reserve(myVec[i].size() + MAX_BUFFER);
    clone.push_back(myVec[i]);
    clone.back().reserve(myVec[i].capacity());
}
```

Comment: This answered my question, thanks :) Do you happen to know whether my compiler can optimize this to only one allocation? I use Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3.

Comment: @anon_user You will have two copy of the string, so the compiler cannot makes only one allocation. If you do not want to keep the old copy, you should [move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) the string.

Comment: @anon_user I'm not sure, but I think the answer is *no*. You have to construct the `std::string` at first, and then `reserve` it.

Comment: @Holt I need the original for further reference. I meant if the copying part could be only one alloc. edit: @ songyuanyao alright, I think I have to resort to char*

Comment: @anon_user In most cases it won't hurt anything. So I suggest you to do performance evaluation and find out the bottleneck, then consider about how to improve it.

Comment: @songyuanyao I come from C background, and I see malloc(a) into realloc(a+b). Even if it wouldn't hurt anything, it seems pointless to me.

Comment: @anon_user C++ and C are different. In C++ we don't use raw pointers, raw array, we use STL containers, smart pointers instead. Don't worry about things which won't hurt. :) Just focus on your design and logic and the encapsulation provided by STL, not the internal implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, string class has a member function
[String resize member funtion..](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/)

Answer (score 0):

`myString.resize(l)` will not change the string's capacity, except when `l` is large then the string's size. Just call `myString.capacity()` and see for yourself.